# Is there a way that I can get the guild id from SocketSlashCommand

Tags: c#, discord.net

Unless I'm thinking about this wrong I have a command that saves data about the guild only `\setfo data pram1 pram2 pram3`. I would like to be able to know what guild I should put that information in. For example:

```
private async Task Client_SlashCommandExecuted(SocketSlashCommand command)
{
    SocketSlashCommandDataOption Option = command.Data.Options.First();
    switch (Option.Name)
    {
        case "edit":
            // Extract and vet the data
            GuildInfo.GetGuildInfoFromGuildID(command.Guild.Id);
            // Save the data
            break;
        default:
            await command.RespondAsync("Unrecognized command.");
            break;
    }

    return;
}
```

I've looked into the `Channel` and the `User` properties of `command` but the only thing that I have found was `User.MutualGuilds` which would cause a major security issue.

Comment: Is `Channel` a base class which can be casted to e.g. `TextChannel` (if the channel Type is a `TextCannel`) which does have a guild?

Comment: @Tvde1 I looked into it deeper and I found `SocketTextChannel` which you can get the guild from I found `SocketChannel` in the docs but I didn't realize that there would be two classes, one for text and one for voice. This is a really weird way of getting around it so def going to make an extension method. I wonder why `SocketChannel` doesn't have a guild accessor because both voice and text channels require a guild unless DMS are bundled in too.

Comment: DMs and group chats are also channels and they do not have a guild, yes

Answer (score 0):

Get the `IServiceProvider` in your class via DI

then you can get the Discord client:

```
DiscordSocketClient _discord = services.GetRequiredService<DiscordSocketClient>();
```

and with that you can get the `SocketGuild`:

```cs
    private async Task DiscordOnSlashCommandExecuted(SocketSlashCommand arg)
        {
            var command = arg.Data.Name;
            SocketGuild guild = _discord.GetGuild(arg.GuildId ?? 0);
     ....
        }
```